# Error creating bean with name 'getTilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I can't run it when I add "Bean" tooooo. I tried adding another maven, and tried lowering the spring boot version. are not the solution
Please tell me what I need to do next. They say I can't create a bean class

this is my error

```
Error creating bean with name 'getTilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/config/tilesconfig.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
```

Here is my entire pom.xml file

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--        -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--        sql-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--        validate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tiles JSP -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my entire tiles.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 
3.0//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="layout" template="/WEB- 
INF/views/layout/index.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB- 
INF/views/layout/_header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB- 
INF/views/layout/_menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="aside" value="/WEB- 
INF/views/layout/_aside.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB- 
INF/views/layout/_footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
<definition name="*/*" extends="layout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB- 
INF/views/{1}/{2}.jsp"/>
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

I don't even know what's the problem.
I make sure the links are correct

Sorry for last all the lines in the same row. I did it because otherwise, it shows as a table on the preview area

Comment: TIles doesn't support JakartaEE and has been removed from the supported frameworks. You arew mixing Spring 6 with Sprng 5.3 which is always going to fail. In short Tiles isn't supported with Spring 6 and thus Spring BOot 3.

Comment: Oh. thanks you very much

Comment: I still can't fix it. Maybe I should recreate another project. or what needs to be done. Please give me some advice

Comment: Read, please read. Tiles doesn't work with Springt Boot 3, simply because the support has been removed from Spring as Tiles doesn't support JakartaEE.